# How do I add a css animation on hover- and click-event?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation-drawer

My goal is to open and close some side-drawer menu with mouse enter or click.

The problem I have is that it just shows it instantly, without any animation slide in left and slide in right. Is it possible to add that with animated CSS?

My attempt so far:

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Paaji+2:wght@400;600&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Baloo Paaji 2', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.top_navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #323233;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.top_navbar .logo {
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
}



.top_navbar .menu {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.top_navbar .hamburger {
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

.top_navbar .hamburger:hover {
    color: #007dc3;
}

/* Now I have determined what the sidebar will look like for a responsive device */
.hover_collapse .sidebar {
    width: 70px;
}

.hover_collapse .sidebar ul li a .text {
    display: none;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #042331;
}

.sidebar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #03374e;
    color: #0e94d4;


}

.sidebar ul li a .icon {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.sidebar ul li a .text {
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.sidebar ul li a:hover {
    background: #0e94d4;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper hover_collapse">
        <div class="top_navbar">
            <div class="logo">Foolish Dev</div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar animate__animated animate__slideInLeft">
            <div class="sidebar_inner">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Shortcuts</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Overview</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Event</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">About</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Service</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-id-card"></i></span>
                            <span class="text">Contact</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var li_items = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar ul li");
        var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
        var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

        li_items.forEach((li_item) => {
            li_item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                li_item.closest(".wrapper").classList.remove("hover_collapse");
            })
        })

        li_items.forEach((li_item) => {
            li_item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                li_item.closest(".wrapper").classList.add("hover_collapse");
            })
        })
        hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
            hamburger.closest(".wrapper").classList.toggle("hover_collapse");
        })
```

This is based on this example:

https://foolishdeveloper.com/responsive-sidebar-menu-using-html-css-and-javascript/

Here is a CodePen example, you will see it just jumps, without the the smooth animation I want:
https://codepen.io/nultien/pen/LYJRYoM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a transition to the sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
   transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
```

You will also need to add this to the links to stop the text wrapping as it transitions:

```
.sidebar ul li a {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

only when you apply the effect do you add the `animated_` classes or integrate it with css see the tutorial: https://animate.style/

I'm sorry I can't fix your code it needs to fix many factors

I believe this is what you want: https://codepen.io/tachib_shin/pen/Exegapz

Comment: I dont understand this is not proper answer to my question

Comment: you are using `animate.css` you need to add class `animate__animated animate__slideInLeft` every time you need it to run the animation and not at the beginning read its document